# Update age column by one year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to update the age column by only one year for each row in the table,
so how to get the  year of that column and increase it by 1.

My data looks like:

```
ID    name     age
1     sarah    1992-05-26 00:00:00
2     suzan    1991-05-20 00:00:00
```

Comment: That looks like a date, not an age. Also, it's probably better not to store the age since you have to run an update every day to make sure the age field stays correct. It would probably be better for you to calculate the age when you need to see it using the DATEDIFF function.

Answer (score 3):

For your specific question you can add one year onto each date with a simple [DateAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
UPDATE DataTable SET Age = DATEADD(year, 1, Age)
```

However, I would store the Date of Birth in the database and calculate the Age in the Business Layer or wherever it needs to be displayed.

For reference, if you do store the Date of Birth, then the age can be calculated with a simple query using a [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function to calculate the number of whole years between the date of birth and todays date:

```
SELECT DT.Name
     , DT.DateOfBirth
     , DATEDIFF(year, DT.DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) As Age
 FROM DataTable DT
```

Answer (score 0):

your query should look like this:

```
Update yourTable set age = DATEADD(yy,1,age)
```

this will increase year by 1